# ASP.NET Core data protection

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm being spammed with errors

```
The key {51a0baee-87ce-4610-848c-383d4f58e3db} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
```

which I think is something to do with something called "ASP.NET data protection".

Any idea what I need to do?
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
string trimmedContentRootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string keyVaultName = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("KeyVaultName");
AspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions = new AspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions() {
  BlobUriWithSasToken = "https://whatever.blob.core.windows.net/whatever-data-protection?sp=racwdl&st=2023-08-14T16:00:04Z&se=2023-08-15T00:00:04Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=%2BDgq2xtgKuaI%2FclYM9AXbKIlLBdg4W%2FuQLBmc53fjR8%3D";
    KeyIdentifier = "https://whatever-key-vault.vault.azure.net/keys/whatever-data-protection/4a1114f79ad94cceaf6761796668c712"
    };
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName(trimmedContentRootPath)
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.BlobUriWithSasToken))
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.KeyIdentifier), new DefaultAzureCredential())
        ;
```

To set up Azure:
Go to the storage service in the resource group and create a new container,
then in the container list click its menu and choose 'Generate SAS'.

Should this secret be stored in the key vault?

Go to the key vault service in the resource group and create a new key.
Click into it, and there is a 'key identifier' property.
This depends on environment but is not secret therefore can be stored in the appsttings.env.json.

But it doesn't work.

```
RequestFailedException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:9820897c-f01e-0014-774c-cf1762000000 Time:2023-08-15T07:47:21.3783363Z Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.) ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed Additional Information: AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Mon, 14 Aug 2023 16:00:04 GMT] - Expiry [Tue, 15 Aug 2023 00:00:04 GMT] - Current [Tue, 15 Aug 2023 07:47:21 GMT] Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:9820897c-f01e-0014-774c-cf1762000000 Time:2023-08-15T07:47:21.3783363Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Mon, 14 Aug 2023 16:00:04 GMT] - Expiry [Tue, 15 Aug 2023 00:00:04 GMT] - Current [Tue, 15 Aug 2023 07:47:21 GMT]</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error> Headers: Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 x-ms-request-id: 9820897c-f01e-0014-774c-cf1762000000 x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2023 07:47:20 GMT Content-Length: 544 Content-Type: application/xml

    Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.DownloadAsync(string snapshot, string versionId, Nullable<int> timeout, string range, string leaseId, Nullable<bool> rangeGetContentMD5, Nullable<bool> rangeGetContentCRC64, string encryptionKey, string encryptionKeySha256, Nullable<EncryptionAlgorithmTypeInternal> encryptionAlgorithm, Nullable<DateTimeOffset> ifModifiedSince, Nullable<DateTimeOffset> ifUnmodifiedSince, string ifMatch, string ifNoneMatch, string ifTags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartDownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, bool rangeGetContentHash, long startOffset, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadStreamingInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, bool rangeGetContentHash, IProgress<long> progressHandler, string operationName, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Azure.Storage.Blobs.PartitionedDownloader.DownloadToAsync(Stream destination, BlobRequestConditions conditions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StagedDownloadAsync(Stream destination, BlobRequestConditions conditions, IProgress<long> progressHandler, StorageTransferOptions transferOptions, bool async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadToAsync(Stream destination, BlobRequestConditions conditions, StorageTransferOptions transferOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs.AzureBlobXmlRepository.GetLatestDataAsync()
    Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs.AzureBlobXmlRepository.GetAllElementsAsync()
    Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Blobs.AzureBlobXmlRepository.GetAllElements()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.GetAllKeys()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, bool forceRefresh)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)
```

Any idea why?
Can it be made to work?

When making the SAS the default expiry time is short and the permissions all neeed checking.

That now produces a different error:

```
RequestFailedException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:766d3595-101e-00a5-084e-cf0977000000
Time:2023-08-15T07:56:41.0260938Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed

Additional Information:
AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature did not match. String to sign used was racwdl
2023-08-15T07:55:37Z
2029-08-15T15:55:37Z
/blob/whatever/$root


https
2022-11-02
c
```

I notice that the string `racwdl` is a GET parameter in the SAS URL thing and doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

The SAS thing simply does not work; use the connection string instead.

The connection string is at
Azure -> Resource group -> storage account -> access keys

Then do

```
    AspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions = new AspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions();
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AspNetCoreDataProtection").Bind(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions);

    builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName(trimmedContentRootPath)
        //.PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.BlobUriWithSasToken))
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.ConnectionString, aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.ContainerName, aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.BlobName)
        .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(aspNetCoreDataProtectionOptions.KeyIdentifier), new DefaultAzureCredential())
        ;
```

Furthermore, in the key vault the `unwrap keys` permission needs to be added to the identity corresponding to the application.